# Filtering rows pairs that follow a specific pattern in column values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file with a column (CODE REF) which stores two type of values (1A and 1X); I am importing it in a Pandas Dataframe. The CODE REF may not always start with 1X but I can find the index of the first row starting with 1X and slice my Dataframe accordingly. I am struggling with the main task which is to filter only rows that follow the sequence 1X1A as shown in picture. I am starting off with the shift method.

Input:

```
  CODE REF
0       1X
1       1A
2       1A
3       1X
4       1A
5       1A
6       1A
7       1X
8       1A
```

Expected output:

```
  CODE REF
0       1X
1       1A
3       1X
4       1A
7       1X
8       1A
```

Comment: please provide your data as text and provide more information on how the problem generalizes

Comment: @mozway it is hard to describe; I guess a better way to say it would be I want to capture only 1X1A pairs; there are no other columns.

Comment: I see, please check my answer. Please next time provide you data as text, not images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a mask to check if a given row is 1X and the next one is 1A, then slice using the mask or its shift:

```
m = df['CODE REF'].eq('1X')&df['CODE REF'].shift(-1).eq('1A')

df[m|m.shift()]
```

Output:

```
  CODE REF
0       1X
1       1A
3       1X
4       1A
7       1X
8       1A
```